# How to use GTM in ReactJS to track all pages upon user consent

Tags: reactjs, cookies, permissions, google-tag-manager, tracking

I have designed a site in ReactJS and have a number of tracking tools and session cookies embedded. Therefore due to the legalisations I need to get user consent first before I can enable any form of tracking. Besides GTM, I have facebook, HotJar and so on.

I am using 'react-cookie-consent' to run the cookie banner. I have managed to control all other cookies/tracking tools by creating functions and only execute them once user has give the relevant consent. I have done the same for GTM however it does not seem to be working properly.

I have imported import TagManager from "react-gtm-module" into my cookie page and put the following code in a function which only runs if user presses accept.

```
const tagManagerArgs = {
  gtmId: "GTM-*******", // My GTMID
  dataLayerName: "PageDataLayer"
};
TagManager.initialize(tagManagerArgs);
```

and have pasted the following code in each page under componentDidMount() function and have imported import TagManager from "react-gtm-module" as well.

```
const tagManagerArgs = {
      dataLayer: {
        page: "home", //Specific to each page
        pagePath: "/home" //Specific to each page
      },
      dataLayerName: "PageDataLayer"
    };
    TagManager.dataLayer(tagManagerArgs);
```

The GTM is triggered once when the user presses the accept button and it appears it is only triggered for the page where the cookie consent banner is on and none of the other pages.

What I want is only when the user presses accept, to then enable the tracking on all pages.

Am I doing something wrong?

Update 01/11/2019
I am still waiting for an answer, not sure if I can repost the question and whether this edit bumps this post :)

Comment: Actually you don't have to put GTM behind consent since GTM is not a _tracking_ software but only tag management system and is used to initiate tracking scripts. It might be easier to have GTM working on all pages and setup up consent dependencies within GTM itself

Comment: Initially I had the JS version of the GTM as given by Google in my index.html file a and a window.dataLayer.push(data) on each page. This was fine and tracking worked on all pages. I do not have much knowledge of GTM and access to the tool, the person who controls is does not know how to handle this either and we have considered the option. The requirements are that it should be done from the code. I think it'll be a fool-proof as well to do form code because if later GTM is changed to another account, it won't require much rework.

Comment: @Дмитро Булах any ideas on this?

Comment: sorry, I'm not that familiar with React and particularly `react-cookie-consent`.  The first thing I'd look into would be checking if `TagManager.initialize` is called each time the relevant consent cookie exists. Not sure I understand your context but what you described makes me think of some pages where consent callback is not running because the cookie was set within previous pages.

Comment: I think that's what's happening as well but I am calling the initilaiser in all pages though. Not really sure where I am going wrong. Do you know if there is a way to bump this post?